# Detecting if a particular Database used Across a Server in a Proc, functions or views

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am looking to find a SQL Code that will help me identify, if a particular database is used or its objects meaning (ex. if there is database name Book and has tables in it)

How do I know if those tables in a database Book are referenced / used in any other databases such as `Procedures`, `Functions`, or `Views` across in a server?

I am trying to refactor objects of a server, so instead of going one by one to every database, I would like to save time.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2017.

Thank you.

Comment: MSSQL 2017, thank you

Comment: My approach would be to use SSMS and script the entire database and objects to a script file. Then you can use text searches for particular key words that you are wanting to find like database names or table names etc.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way is to examine all the view, trigger, and stored procedure text for occurrences of the database name, and manually review the matches.

eg run this in each database

```
select db_name(), o.name object_name, o.type_desc, m.definition
from sys.sql_modules m
join sys.objects o 
  on m.object_id = o.object_id
where definition like '%book%'
```

and examine the results.  This should catch almost all uses of the database in static and dynamic SQL.  It's always *possible* that this would miss dynamic cross-database queries where the target database name is not present in the source code, but it should be good enough for your purpose.

Comment: This is perfect, Thank you David.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to use the free SQL Search Tool by Red Gate Software. 
https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/